# Start with delayed_job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I have a task that needs to be repeat every 10 minutes.
I want to use `delayed_job`, but I can not find a tutorial how to use it correctly for my problem. For example

```
 class A
   def print
     p Time.now
   end
 end
```

Where should I place this class?
Then where should I call this method (`print`), so it was repeated every 10 minutes?
It does not depend the user, does not depend on entries in database.

Thanks.

Comment: WHat's the connection with delayed job ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid whenever if you wish to save resources (i.e. with rails ; since you have tagged your question with rails)

Whenever loads the whole rails environment every time you need to do something. It can be useful if you're running a simple ruby script.

[rufus-scheduler](https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler) is the gem to use.

```
# config/initializers/chrons.rb

require 'rufus-scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

scheduler.every '3m' do
  p Time.now  
end
```

If you have a job that would take a long time to process (i.e. sending an email, processing an image, etc), this is when you would need delayed_job.

There's a famous gem, [delayed_job_active_record](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job_active_record) that helps with that or a gem that I've recently written,  [delayed_job_active_record_threaded](https://github.com/zxiest/delayed_job_active_record_threaded), which uses threads instead of processes. This allows faster processing with less resource usage and database hitting.

Answer (score 2):

Your objective asks more for something like https://github.com/javan/whenever which is basically a generator for crontab files in UNIX based systems.

Comment: That is delayed_job should be used when there are actions that are associated with the database?

Comment: delayed_job is used when you want a long running task (let's say 5 minutes) to be triggered by a web action. The web action should not take 5 minutes to complete (because the user would assume that your web app is broken somehow). So you give the job to a background process which is created and maintained by delayed_job.